# Windows scheduler isnt calling other python files from main python

Tags: python

I have a requirement a parent python script calling multiple other python script along with the parameter.

I have created a bat file calling the parent python script. When I run the parent python script/bat file all the other python files called inside the parent python script gets executed but in scheduler those files get skipped. However with proper logging I'm able to see to commands before and after the call of child python files are getting executed.

Comment: Are the Python script files given with a relative path? If so, use an absolute path instead.

Comment: This is the code in the calling python script -  import os
os.system("feed1.py "+str(100)) .... The same python script if run via a bat file is still working. I even tried giving the absolute path as well but not luck when running via the windows scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Before calling any python code inside the another python code, the execute location goes to the windows default execute location and that was the reason child python files werent called.

use `os.chdir()` to change the working directory to the child python location